# Getting Connection reset error while downloading dependency

Tags: gitlab, salesforce, mule, gitlab-ci-runner, jitpack

I am getting Connection reset error while downloading dependency.
If i remove below two dependency from pom then its working fine but if i add these dependecy then its failing with below error.

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-salesforce-connector</artifactId>
            <version>10.6.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-salesforce-composite-connector</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

**Error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project project: Could not resolve dependencies for project project-sapi:mule-application:1.0.1: Could not transfer artifact com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema:jar:1.9.2 from/to jitpack (https://jitpack.io/): Connection reset -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project project-sapi: Could not resolve dependencies for project au.com.aims.vga:vga-aims-common-s3-sapi:mule-application:1.0.1: Could not transfer artifact com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema:jar:1.9.2 from/to jitpack (https://jitpack.io/): Connection reset
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.DependencyResolutionException: Could not resolve dependencies for project project-sapi:mule-application:1.0.1: Could not transfer artifact com.github.everit-org.json-schema:org.everit.json.schema:jar:1.9.2 from/to jitpack (https://jitpack.io/): Connection reset
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Maven is trying to download a dependency from the repository https://jitpack.io, but it is failing to access it. It is probably a repository added in your pom or settings.xml. That dependency is available in MuleSoft Public repository so you could try adding MuleSoft public repository instead. See the instructions at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/configuring-maven-to-work-with-mule-esb#referencing-the-public-mulesoft-repositories

Comment: tried this..now org.everit.json.schema:jar:1.9.2 got downloaded.
But now Connection Reset error coming for downloading org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:pom:3.0

Comment: Something is wrong with the https://jitpack.io/ repository. Either fix the repository or remove it.

Comment: For now, i have also added maven repo along with Mule public repo and its working.